# Ansible collection with role-scope custom modules

Tags: ansible, ansible-role, ansible-collections

I am trying to convert my pile of Ansible playbooks, roles, tasks, etc into a formalized [Ansible Collection](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/collections_using.html) to better support re-use and modularity.

The TL;DR is that I am having issues packaging a collection that includes a role that includes a custom module. Previously I could invoke a role's custom module from any taskfile in the role without a Fully Qualified Collection Name (FQCN). However, with the role packaged as part of a collection, Ansible says it cannot resolve the role's custom module name.

---

Within this collection I have all of the following:

- A playbook, `foobook.yml`
- A custom module, `my_baz_module`
- A role, `bar_role`
- A custom module within `bar_role`, `my_bar_role_module`

This leads to the below directory structure:

```
mynamespace/
\─ mycollection/
   |─ playbooks/
   |  \─ foobook.yml
   ├─ plugins/
   |  \─ modules/
   |     \─ my_baz_module.py
   \─ roles/
      \─ bar_role/
         ├─ tasks/
         |  \─ main.yml
         \─ library/
            \─ my_bar_role_module.py
```

This structure lets me run the playbook with `ansible-playbook mynamespace.mycollection.foobook ...`, and within that playbook access the role with `role: mynamespace.mycollection.bar_role`. In either the role or the playbook I can invoke a task that uses `my_baz_module` like below:

```yaml
- name: My task 
  mynamespace.mycollection.my_baz_module:
    ...
```

However, in `roles/bar_role/tasks/main.yml` I cannot invoke a task like either of the below or I get the following errors:

```yaml
# method one
- name: My task
  my_bar_role_module:
    ...

# method two
- name: My task
  mynamespace.mycollection.my_bar_role_module:
    ...

# method three, though I didn't expect this to work (and it didn't)
- name: My task
  mynamespace.mycollection.bar_role.my_bar_role_module:
    ...
```

```
# Error from method one
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'my_bar_role_module'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.

# Error from method two
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'mynamespace.mycollection.my_bar_role_module'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.
```

To be clear: this is a change directly related to the transition to the collection structure. Before moving this content to a collection I could invoke `my_bar_role_module` from any taskfile in `bar_role` without any problems. Is there any way to support this structure without packaging the role separately or moving `my_bar_role_module` to the collection-scope plugins directory?

EDIT: The playbook is being launched with `ansible-playbook mynamespace.mycollection.foobook`. An example playbook is below:

```yaml
# foobook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - role: mynamespace.mycollection.bar_role
```

Comment: Please edit with the exact command used to launch the playbook

Comment: @Zeitounator edited with playbook command and example playbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shipping modules inside collection roles is [deliberately not supported](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_locally.html#adding-standalone-local-modules-for-selected-playbooks-or-a-single-role); you must include them as normal collection modules. You can if you wish use a sub-directory to indicate that the module is not intended for external use, e.g. by placing it at `plugins/modules/internal/my_bar_module.py` and calling `mynamespace.mycollection.internal.my_bar_module`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Confirmation that this is or is not possible is exactly what I was looking for. Do you know if/where this is documented by any chance?

Comment: In the documentation for plugins inside of roles. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_locally.html#adding-standalone-local-modules-for-selected-playbooks-or-a-single-role